# How to combine schema.org, RDFa and DBpedia in HTML?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, dbpedia, rdfs

I need to embed RDFa data into HTML using Schema.org and DBpedia.

Here is the HTML code (without DBpedia):

```
<div vocab="https://schema.org/" typeof="Organization">
  <span property="name">Google</span>
About the company:
    About:<span property="description">Google LLC (/ˈɡuːɡəl/) is an American multinational technology company that focuses on search engine technology, online advertising, cloud computing, computer software.....</span>,
    Logo:<span property="logo">http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Google_2015_logo.svg?width=300</span>
```

I would like to declare also that the information is from DBpedia.

For example for the first line of code, I want to add also that the typeof="Organization" is also a dbo:Company or sameAs.

For the second line of code, I want to add that the property="name", Google is the rdfs:label of https://dbpedia.org/page/Google

The 4th line of code the property="description" is actually the rdfs:comment from https://dbpedia.org/page/Google page.

And the last line of code, the property="logo" is the dbo:thumbnail of https://dbpedia.org/page/Google page which is http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Google_2015_logo.svg?width=300.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply properties/types from different ontologies, it’s best to use RDFa’s `prefix` (instead of `vocab`):

```html
<html prefix="schema: http://schema.org/ rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# dbo: http://dbpedia.org/ontology/ owl: http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#">
```

```html
<div typeof="schema:Organization dbo:Company">
  
  <span property="schema:name rdfs:label">Google</span>

  <span property="schema:description rdfs:comment">Google is an …</span>

  <img property="schema:logo dbo:thumbnail" src="http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Google_2015_logo.svg?width=300" alt="" /> 
  <!-- see note 1 -->

</div>
```

To state that the organization you describe is the same organization DBpedia describes, you can add:

```html
<link property="owl:sameAs" href="http://dbpedia.org/resource/Google" />
<!-- see note 2 -->
```

All that doesn’t convey which values you *took* from DBpedia, though. To state the source of each single statement, you could use [reification](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/#ch_reificationvocab) (making statements about statements).
Instead of using that elaborate method, maybe it would work for you to just state the content license (+ attributing DBpedia) of your page, or page section.

---

Note 1: To get a URL (instead of a string) as value for `schema:logo`/`dbo:thumbnail`, make sure to use an HTML element with `href` or `src` attribute (`a`, `img`, `link` etc.).

Note 2: Make sure to use the URI with `/resource/` (which represents the thing), not `/page/` (which represents the page about the thing).

Comment: @Stefan-brox-it-solutions - This is helpful! Thank you! I will use the above example as a starting point for a much longer and complex html page. Any suggestions on how to check/verify if the code is machine-readable and maybe how the browsers or search engines interprets the code?